# What happened to the Auto Stack Exchange site?

Tags: discussion, stack-exchange

I have found the Area51 site, and have figured out that that is the only way to create a new site in Stack Exchange, but what happened to the old site.

If it was taken down, what happened the questions and answers?

Please forgive me if this is off topic for meta.stackoverflow I've been away for a while and wasn't sure where to ask.

Update: There was a user by the name of "cigars and absinthe" or similar that was a moderator for that site, but with all the name changing on meta, I am not sure which user he is.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/ is for questions about SE 1.0 sites.

Comment: You're almost certainly thinking of [John Rudy](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/14048/john-rudy). I remember him as "Cigars and Bourbon are Good"; he's also been "Cigars and Absinthe are Great." See [the unofficial, incomplete name change list](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19478/the-many-memes-of-meta/26518#26518) for more information than you would ever want.

Answer (score 6):

You should go to http://mechanics.stackexchange.com

Comment: And be patient for 6 days!

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you're describing a StackExchange 1.0 site. Originally StackExchange allowed anyone to start a site if they wanted to, but charged them a monthly fee. After a couple months they changed it so instead sites are created through Area 51 but are free; generally called StackExchange 2.0. As far as I know there isn't an official list of the SE 1.0 sites, since they were owned by third parties instead of the SE owners. There's a [community-maintained list](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4/list-of-stackexchange-1-0-sites), but I don't see the site you're describing on it

---

**Edit**: Popular Demand pointed out that that link is broken now; S.Mark cloned it [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/40784/is-this-a-stack-exchange-website/40787#40787)

Comment: That list is grossly out of date. Of the few SE 1.0 site owners who have decided to continue, most have already made other arrangements to host their site. If the site no longer appears at its previous URL, the original owner has likely decided to move on and *not* continue their site.

Comment: As of a few days ago, the that link (http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4/list-of-stackexchange-sites) no longer exists. All `meta.stackexchange.com` URLs redirect to the MSO main page.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, if you want an Autos Stack Exchange site for general questions instead of just about repair/maintenance, go here:

http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/7435/autos

To help get the site off the ground, just follow the proposal and vote the sample questions as on/off topic.